# Running Android Room queries on SyncAdapter

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-room, android-thread

Android Room queries can't be executed on the main thread, then normally I use Handler or AsyncTask from an Activity. However, when in need to persist data in a SyncAdapter, what is the correct way to execute Room queries in a different thread? (I need to do some requests to REST APIs and persist the result data).

Currently the way I do is using AsyncTask, but the docs say that AsyncTask should be short lived and I'm having some troubles with context leak.

```
static class PushUpdatedTasksToServerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Task, Integer, Void> {

        private final Context mContext; // Android Lint alerts a possible context leak
        private final TaskDAO mDao;

        PushUpdatedTasksToServerAsyncTask(Context context, TaskDAO dao) {
            mContext = context;
            mDao = dao;
        }
```

**Update to clarify the current scenario**

My SyncAdapter does three operations:

1. Push local changes to server (query local DB using Room and post to REST Api);
2. Get server data (query REST Api and save to local DB using Room);
3. Remove old (unnecessary) data from local DB (delete using Room).

Currently, when I need to access the local DB using room, I use an AsyncTask so I don't receive the error saying that I can't access the DB from the main thread.

However I also have to query or post to the REST Api, using retrofit2 enqueue, so it runs in another thread. The code becomes a mess as I can only call the next step after the current one finishes, and with one thread being created inside the other, the debug is painful.

Is it right? Shouldn't I use another threading option?

Comment: did you try rxjava ??

Comment: `"queries can't be executed on the main thread"` that is not true you can set it so they can

Comment: Also you can set your context in your task as a `WeakReference` so that it can be garbage collected

Comment: @tyczj I'm assuming that just because I can, doesn't mean I should. :-) I'm updating the question to explain the scenario why I'm worried about context leak and maybe you can say if it can be a problem or not.

Comment: Why not use an `IntentService`?

Comment: Do you mean an `IntentService` called by the `SyncAdapter`?

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira Yes or just remove the SyncAdapter and just use an IntentService

Comment: Wait dosen't syncAdapter run in a background thread already? `Note: The sync adapter framework runs onPerformSync() on a background thread, so you don't have to set up your own background processing.`

Comment: If it runs in a background thread, I can't understand why the Room lib says that I can't run queries in the UI Thread. I'll review my code to understand what's really happening.

Comment: do you have found a solution? I've got the same issue.

Comment: In my case the problem seems to be related to the fact that I use AsyncTasks in the SyncAdapter, so if I place code in the PostExecute event it is executed in the main thread, thus causing the error. I suppose this is the cause, but I have changed most of my code and the problem seems to be gone.